# How to get the Link or InnerText using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, winforms, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I have this structure:

```
<p class="info">Sample：
    <strong>
       <a href="http://PleaseGetMe.com"target="_blank">http://PleaseGetMe.com</a>
    </strong> 
</p>
```

What I want is to get the http://PleaseGetMe.com

Here is what I'm trying:

```
                var a = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@class='info']//a");
                Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Which is not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Implementation

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//*[@class='info']//a"))
                {
                    string value = node.InnerText;
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
```